# How to get data using page, param and native query in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to read data using a query and want to use the inbuilt page and then map my result.
I am using postgres database.
I couldn't find single example.

**Repository**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT jobsModel.* from JobsModel jobsModel WHERE jobsModel.jobState =:jobState AND " +
        "jobsModel.id NOT IN (SELECT jobApplicationModel.jobId FROM JobApplicationModel jobApplicationModel WHERE jobApplicationModel.userId =:userId)" +
        "and jobsModel.id NOT IN (SELECT savedJobModel.jobId FROM SavedJobModel savedJobModel WHERE savedJobModel.userId =:userId) " +
        "and jobsModel.id NOT IN (SELECT userJobLikeDislikeModel.jobId FROM UserJobLikeDislikeModel userJobLikeDislikeModel WHERE " +
        "userJobLikeDislikeModel.relevance<>-1 and userJobLikeDislikeModel.userId=:userId)",
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(jobsModel.*) from JobsModel jobsModel WHERE jobsModel.jobState =:jobState AND " +
                " jobsModel.id NOT IN (SELECT jobApplicationModel.jobId FROM JobApplicationModel jobApplicationModel WHERE jobApplicationModel.userId =:userId) " +
                " and jobsModel.id NOT IN (SELECT savedJobModel.jobId FROM SavedJobModel savedJobModel WHERE savedJobModel.userId =:userId) " +
                " and jobsModel.id NOT IN (SELECT userJobLikeDislikeModel.jobId FROM UserJobLikeDislikeModel userJobLikeDislikeModel WHERE " +
                " userJobLikeDislikeModel.relevance<>-1 and userJobLikeDislikeModel.userId=:userId)", nativeQuery = true)
```

**JobsModel**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
// FIXME: create lombok getter setters
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
@Table(name="job")
public class JobsModel {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;
    private String source;

    @Column(name = "job_state")
    private String jobState;

    @Column(name = "dateModified")
    private Date dateModified;

    @Column(name = "due_date")
    private Date dueDate;

    private Date created;
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: we can always fallback to jpql queries. going directly to native queries i will not recommend unless a particular query is not possible or there are performance issues

Comment: @Query(value = "select * from job where job_state='PUBLISHED' and is_deleted=false and id " +
            " not in(select job_id from application where user_id=:userId) and id non in " +
            "(select job_id from user_job_saved where user_id=:userId) and id not in " +
            "(select job_id from user_job_like_dislike where user_id=:userId and like_dislike <> 1)",
    nativeQuery = true)